# The fourth-last digit of $N=3^{3^{3^{3^{3^3}}}}$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Is there a way to calculate the fourth-last digit of the number $N=3^{3^{3^{3^{3^3}}}}$ (six threes)? I know this is a kind of silly question but I think direct calculation is not a good trial. Can I get some little hints? I know little about elementary number theory (some famous theorems such as Fermat's little theorem, Euler's theorem, etc, but I'm not sure that these are needed.)

Comment: Maybe calculate it normally but omit everything beyond  the 4th last digit?

Comment: @justabit can you clarify what you mean by calculate it "normally"? Because working right-to-left from the top of the power tower downwards is what I would interpret that as meaning, and that is obviously undoable (truncating powers to being 4 digits long will not yield a correct result).

Comment: What's the source of the question?

Comment: @GrafZahl How did you get $27^27$?

Comment: @MarkSaving By stupidity, that's why I deleted it.

Comment: Oh nvm it's totally wrong

Comment: Let $A_1=3$ and $A_{n+1}=3^{A_n}$. Then we need $A_6\pmod{10000}$, for that $A_5\pmod{\varphi(10000)}$, and so on..

Comment: $$\phi(10000)=4000$$ $$\phi(4000)=1600$$ $$\phi(1600)=640$$ $$\phi(640)=256$$ $$\phi(256)=128$$ $$\phi(128)=64$$ ... Doesn't get us far sadly ... Observation that $$3^6=2187$$ might help ...

Comment: @Calum Gilhooley, IBM Ponder This had a similar question in 2014, https://www.research.ibm.com/haifa/ponderthis/challenges/October2014.html

Answer (score 1):

For brevity, define $N_0 = 1$ and $N_{i + 1} = 3^{N_i}$. We wish to compute the fourth digit of $N_6$. To do this, we will need to compute $N_6$ modulo $10^4$.

We see that $N_0 = 1$.

We see that $N_1 = 3$.

We see that $N_2 = 27$.

We see that $N_3 \equiv 187 \mod 640$.

We see that $N_4 = 3^{N_3} \equiv 3^{187} \equiv 187 \mod 1600$.

We see that $N_5 = 3^{N_4} \equiv 3^{187} \equiv 3387 \mod 4000$.

We see that $N_6 = 3^{N_5} \equiv 3^{3387} \equiv 5387 \mod 10000$.

Note that we are computing repeated totients of $10^4$ to make this work.

Thus, the fourth-to-last digit is a 5.

Comment: @RoddyMacPhee 'Twas indeed a typo. It is now correct. Thanks!

Comment: You can Also decrease the work $\mathrm{znorder}(\mathrm{Mod}(3,10000))=500$ by PARI/GP. So the path goes to $$500,100,20,4,2$$

Comment: How do we get $N_3=187$ mod 640? by direct calculation?

Comment: @user302934 By manually doing the math. It's pretty gnarly, unfortunately, but it's easy to verify with a computer.